# User Information on entities symfony

Tags: symfony, entities

I started using symfony not long ago and at the moment I'm struggling with this problem:

I decided to have "who" information at entity level so I have defined these additional 4 prameters for every entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="created_by", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $createdBy;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
 */
private $createdAt;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="updated_by", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $updatedBy;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $updatedAt;
```

My problem is now where and how I should populate createdBy and updatedBy. ATM I do that in my controller before persisting to the database. Thou I encountered a problem when a entity is a property of another entity and lets say I have an entity called Post that has a property images of type Document the entities Post and Document both have "who" information on them and images property inside Post is defined as follows:

```
/**
 * @var array
 *  
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Nisand\DocumentsBundle\Entity\Document", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="blog_documents",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="post_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="document_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
private $images;
```

For Post suppose I set createdBy in the controller before persisting but on Document how should that work cause that will be persisted by the cascade rule?

How do you guys handle in your applications the "who" columns?

Answer (score 1):

Try this bundle: [StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/index.html) and use `Blameable` extension.

You will need set current user with `BlameableListener`. And it will cover your use case.

Documentation for `Blameable` is here: https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/blameable.md

Comment: https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors does the same I know about them I want to do it myself else I end up with 30 3th party Bundles that i have to understand and examine and learn also to use.

Comment: stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle is much more popular than KNP solution. 3324842 vs 285424 downloads (from packagist.org). But choice is yours. Remember that KNP library require php >= 5.4 and stof  require php >= 5.3.2. Both solution are similar. Glad that my answer pointed you in correct direction.